# Browser to wait for Angular app to be loaded

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new in angular 4. I created a simple app that get data from API and display it. I tried some Google tools to see how Google see the page. Google see empty page (I expected this, because everything is asynchronously). Is there a way to tell to browser when app is finished. I want google scraper to wait async things to finish.

Here is how Google Mobile-Friendly Test tool see my page (you can find my page there): https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=hKrq8xL_l5n0Mxp988JvWw

Thanks!

Comment: I think SEO of Angular apps go through [server-side rendering](https://universal.angular.io/)

Comment: you can use angular universal and do server pre rendering, that will help you in SEO and I believe google won't see empty page which on client side rendering it will. this is a good read https://scotch.io/tutorials/server-side-rendering-in-angular-2-with-angular-universal

Comment: I'm looking for something simple or workaround (include slow loading image in css)

Comment: @VasilNikolov Can you add any reference app where Angular4 is crawled by Google?